# ScrollView не прокручивается до конца

Tags: android, android-scrollview

Динамически добавляю карточки в scrollview но они не прокручиваются до конца. Как поправить?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    tools:context=".DesktopActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/requestUpTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
        android:text="Заявки"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:textColor="#4C4B5E"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/OnOffServiceBtn"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/newTextView"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
        android:text="Новые: 0"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:textColor="#4C4B5E"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/requestUpTextView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/requestUpTextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/inWorkTextView"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
        android:text="В работе: 0"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:textColor="#4C4B5E"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/newTextView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/newTextView" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/OnOffServiceBtn"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ImageButton"
        android:layout_width="58dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:src="@drawable/connection_ready"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
        style="@style/toggleButton"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="29dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_toggle_bg"
        android:onClick="onTrayBtn"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/OnOffServiceBtn"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/OnOffServiceBtn" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:paddingBottom="300dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toggleButton">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraint"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/requestTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
        android:text=" Заявки"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/request_ico"
        android:textColor="#4C4B5E"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/OnOffServiceBtn" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/countNewTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle_red"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/requestTextView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/requestTextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/countInWorkTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
        android:text="0"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle_orange"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/countNewTextView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/requestTextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/surveyTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
        android:text=" Опросы"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/survey_ico"
        android:textColor="#4C4B5E"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/requestTextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/settingsTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
        android:text=" Настройки"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/settings_ico"
        android:textColor="#4C4B5E"
        android:textSize="26sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/surveyTextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/logoTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="120dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/zchbu_small_ico"
        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
        android:text="  ЦБУ Мастер"
        android:textColor="#F4BA00"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpaVz.png]

Comment: Поменяйте `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` на `android:layout_height="match_parent"` для `ScrollView`. И ширину тоже не стоит `wrap_content` делать.

Answer (score 0):

Перерыл кучу информации. Помогла только установка высоты скроллируемого элемента в `android:layout_height="Величина которая точно перекроет всё содержимое в dp"`. При этом `android:layout_height="match_parent"` не решает. Фух. Это сделало трюк для меня)